# Laravel Common Services Through Inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel-5

Question.

I have a bunch of controllers that are using a certain set of services. I was wondering if it is possible / right to utilize inheritance to save me from having to inject them into controllers all the time. This is what I was planning on doing.

```
class MasterController extends controller{
    public function _construct(){
            $this->userData = App::make(UserService::class)
            $this->fooData = App::make(FooService::class)
    }
}

class UserController extends MasterController {
    public function __construct(BashService $bashService){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bashData = $bashService;
    }

    public function someFunction(){
        $something = $this->userData->doUserSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea to do? A really bad idea to do? Why or why not? I thought this might save me from having to inject common services again and again into controllers.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use traits to create a composition of needed functionality? It's another way of adding it besides using inheritance, the plus side is that you will not be restricted combining needed functionality by not being able to inherit from multiple classes at once.

Comment: I thought about that but it did not feel right as traits are meant for cases where you need a specific set of methods. This is more for including other classes and the intent was just so that all the controller constructors are not stuffed like crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:**

> I was wondering if it is possible/right to utilize inheritance to save me from having to inject them into controllers all the time.

**Answer:**

1. Yes it is possible and it is right to utilize inheritance as by
   following this, you will keep your controller clean which means you
   can have functions in your controller but the function will lead to
   a different function implemented or inherited from a different class.

**Question:**

> Is this a good idea to do?

**Answer:**

1. Obviously, A big YES it is a good idea as I have mentioned above
   keeping your controller clean is the best practice one can follow
   since your methods will be separated from the business logic where
   you implement all the fetching and posting and calculation and what
   not since your controller is clean and all the methods actions
   return from a different class with accurate response eg(true or
   false).

**Question:**

> Why or why not?

**Answer:**

1. Since I have explained most of the part, I would further like to go
   with to suggest you the repository pattern so basically by the
   word repository I mean this :

   - A source code repository is a file archive and web hosting facility    where a large amount of source code, for software or for
     web pages,    is kept, either publicly or privately. They are often
     used by open-source software projects and other multi-developer
     projects to handle various versions.

   In laravel you can follow repository pattern to code your project
   which is currently found the best practice.

   You can do a google search too on laravel repository [pattern.](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=YKE8W_SoJ8yBvQSo6KiQCw&q=laravel%20repository%20pattern&oq=Larave%20repo&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0i13k1l9.850968.852799.0.854741.11.10.0.0.0.0.367.1889.2-5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.7.1887...0i67k1j0i10k1.0.ESgbkkfessA)

   I have an example which will make you understand [this.](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce)

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thanks for your comment. I am familiar with the repository pattern and I actually use it in my service layer. the flow I am using is controller->service->repo. In the service I do any business logic needed, this way I can keep my controllers lean and my repo's only for DB activities.